# load-on-startup of Subversion

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server, apache-modules

We used VisualSVN Server 2.5.8 in our windows machine. we have to invoke the script whenever the VisualSVN Server restarted.

How do we invoke the script on VSVN Start-up ?

Comment: What's the script's task? Why do you restart the server?

Comment: to get the server start-up time...

Answer (score 0):

> to get the server start-up time

You don't need to run any special script to know when VisualSVN Server started, restarted or stopped. Events related to VisualSVN Server services are always written to "VisualSVN Server" Windows Event Log. Therefore, you can either manually check the log via Windows Event Viewer or use PowerShell script. Here is a script example:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName VisualSVNServer | Where-Object {$_.Message -Match "resuming normal operations"}
```

**NOTE:** [`Get-EventLog`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) cmdlet is available starting with PowerShell 3.0. In other words, PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0 do not include this cmdlet.